# need to get input array value to controller

Tags: angularjs

I need to get array values from form to controller and could not find a way to do so.

HTML Form:

```
<div class="input-wrap">
     <label>CNC Location</label>
     <div class="input-inner">
         <div class="input-area input-row">
            <input type="text" id="latitude" name="locationLat" ng-model="actorData.cncLocation['lat']"  placeholder="Latitude">
            <input type="text" id="longitude" name="locationLong" ng-model="actorData.cncLocation['long']" placeholder="Longitude">
            <input type="text" id="location-name" name="locationName" ng-model="actorData.cncLocation['name']" placeholder="Name">
         </div>
         <div class="buttons-area">
           <a href class="remove-row"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a>
           <a href class="add-row" ng-click="addRow()"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div ng-messages="actorForm.cncLocation.$dirty && actorForm.cncLocation.$error">
     <span class="error-msg" ng-message="required">Required</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.forEach($scope.actorData.cncLocation, function(){
   $scope.cncLocation.push($scope.actorData.cncLocation);
   console.log($scope.cncLocation);
});
```

I need to send cncLocation array with objects which includes `{"lat": "", "long":"", "name":""}` where user can add and remove rows.

Comment: Why are using a loop. You can directly push the object into the array b $scope.cncLocation.push({"lat": $scope.actorData.cncLocation['lat'], "long"$scope.actorData.cncLocation['long'], "name":$scope.actorData.cncLocation['name']})

Comment: @Vivz bro this way I am only getting first row values whereas I have multiple rows.

Comment: How do you have multiple rows? Are you using ng-repeat?

Comment: @vivz, not using ng-repeat, see my html, where user can add/remove rows so I need to get all rows values into controller

Comment: But how are you distinguishing between the ng-models of two rows?

Comment: @Vivz I don't know :) please do corrections